# The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property (WebMethod)

Tags: asp.net, json, webforms, webmethod

#### Background

I have a `WebMethod` in the code-behind for an ASPX page:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetServiceDetail()
{
    //...
}
```

I'm using jQuery to send an AJAX request to it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + "GetServiceDetail",
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
})
```

This generally works correctly.

#### Problem

When the `WebMethod` returns about 88KB of data, the framework returns a `500 Internal Server Error` to the HTTP request.  The HTTP response body contains a bunch of .NET exception information in JSON format. When deserialised, the response has this information:

> `System.InvalidOperationException`:
>
> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). The length of the string exceeds the value set on the `maxJsonLength` property.

```
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)
```

#### Troubleshooting

- I'm not using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) in the `WebMethod` at all. As the stack trace shows, the exception is happening outside of my code.
- Existing StackOverflow questions seem to be about explicit JSON serialisation or different technologies. They imply changing the Web.config value doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by changing an attribute called [`maxJsonlength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb513882(v=vs.100).aspx) in `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="4000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Sourced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/238753.